# How to suppress error messages which is coming from other procedure? - PROGRESS 4GL

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I am using below query to catch errors but I don't want to use these procedures. Instead, I need to suppress the error messages which should not throw during run time.

```
DO ON ERROR UNDO, THROW:
   FIND Customer 1000.
END.

CATCH eAnyError AS Progress.Lang.Error:
  MESSAGE
   "Error Number:~t" eAnyError:GetMessageNum(1) "~n"
   "Error Text:~t" eAnyError:GetMessage(1)
   VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX BUTTONS OK TITLE "Error processing in the CATCH for mainprocedure block".
 END CATCH.
```

Comment: `FIND customer 1000 NO-ERROR.` ?

Comment: I gave an example of it. But actually I want to know how to suppress errors from calling program in main program

Comment: Create an example that really shows you problem!

Answer (score 2):

Use `FIND` with `NO-ERROR` function.

Or even better yet, use `IF AVAIL` before trying to make any modifications, this way it only try to change if it can find the field.

```
FIND Customer 1000 NO-ERROR.

IF AVAIL Customer THEN DO:
    // Customer exists
END. ELSE DO:
    // There is no customer 1000
END.
```